# Register device on GCM: onRegistered isn't called

Tags: android, registration, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM on my application, but when I try to register my device the onRegistered method on GCMIntentService isn't called.

I installed the GCM demo application on my device and it works:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

In this app the device is registered and I can send messages to it. I tried to use GCM in my own app using the same GCMIntentService. I adapted the manifest too, but when I try to register this is what appears in my log:

09-25 10:00:10.195: V/GCMRegistrar(591): Registering app com.pfc.dps of senders 38322290XXXXX

And nothing else, I get no response. These are my manifest permissions:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pfc.dps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.pfc.dps.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.pfc.dps.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I created a new project in Google APIs console to check if it worked that way, but I get the same result using any of the Sender IDs.

Does anybody know why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: You keep GCMIntentService in root application package with correct category?

Comment: Actually it's in the package com.pfc.dps.gcm. What do I need to change? The C2D_MESSAGE permission? Or I have to move the GCMIntentService to the root package?

Comment: You must keep GCMIntentService.class in package that signed your application        in AndroidManifest.xml - > com.pfc.dps

Comment: I've moved GCMIntentSevice, CommonUtilities and ServerUtilities to the package com.pfc.dps, but it's still the same :(

Comment: Check your device ip address and sender id.If you will do step by step as it describe in http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html it should works

Comment: Please can you show us your complete Menifest and Code you have Done for GCM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the "Registering app ***your_package*** of senders ***sender_id***"

You should receive a `onReceive` event which will call your `GCMIntentService` to wake your app up.

If you do not have that, please check you have missed the receiver or forgotten to change the category for your own package.

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
       <category android:name="***your_package***" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Finally I decided to adapt the demo manifest to my app and it worked, I guess I had something wrong with my receiver since everything else was fine.